# re: Match any word in a set repeating

Tags: python, regex

Given a set of space delimited words that may come in any order how can I match only those words in a given set of words. For example say I have:

`apple monkey banana dog` and I want to match `apple` and `banana` how might I do that?

Here's what I've tried:

```
m = re.search("(?P<fruit>[apple|banana]*)", "apple monkey banana dog")
m.groupdict() --> {'fruit':'apple'}
```

But I want to match both apple and banana.

Answer (score 1):

In `(?P<fruit>[apple|banana]*)`

[apple|banana]* defines a character class, e.g. this token matches one a, one p, one l, one e, one |, one b or one n, and then says 'match this 0 or more times'. (You probably meant to use a +, anyway, which would mean 'match one or more times')

What you want is (apple|banana) which will match the string apple or the string banana.

Learn more: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

For your next question, to get all matches a regex makes against a string, not just the first, use http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall

Comment: I've tried that, and your right it does match the string apple OR banana I need it to match apple AND banana repeating zero or more times. Maybe I should have clarified more.

Comment: @john-charles Your regex was flawed anyway and you would have found out sooner or later :) I have amended my answer to also give the answer you were after.

Comment: No, I meant zero or more times. Anyway, theres no way to multiply match specific words in the same regex? This is only part of what I need to regex to do. Using findall would require that I findall then apply another regex to each found match.

Comment: @john-charles If you have to apply another regex, so be it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be able to repeat, you're going to fail on white space. Try this:

```
input = ['apple','banana','orange']
reg_string = '(' + ('|').join(input) + ')'
lookahead_string = '(\s(?=' + ('|').join(input) + '))?' + reg_string + '?'
out_reg_string = reg_string + (len(input)-1)*lookahead_string
matches = re.findall(out_reg_string, string_to_match)
```

where `string_to_match` is what you are looking for the pattern within. `out_reg_string` can be used to match something like:

- "apple banana orange"
- "apple orange"
- "apple banana"
- "banana apple"

or any of the cartesian product of your input list.